# Organise views/buttons after changing the font (setting->display->fontsize)

Tags: android, android-layout

The layout has just two buttons in a linear layout and it looks like the following when the font size is default (setting->display->fontsize).
[image]

Now if I change the font to bigger size, it becomes to

[image]

But I would like to show the following

[image]

I wrote a custom linearlayout and tried to manipulate the layout's parameters based on the linecount in `onLayout` function. Most of the time it works well. However if the layout is part of nestedscrollview, it starts flickering.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you not simply default to what you have in the 3rd screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the design requirements.